# Rails 3.2 and will_paginate, customize generated paginate links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I have a single page site that has different controller actions in a carousel.  Works the way I like right now.  I'd like to paginate the results. By default will_paginate is generating  links that look like this:

**/links/new?page=3#make-links**

I need this path to look like:

**/?page=3#show-links**

I have this method in my controller that I call in any action that needs pagination:

```
@links = Link.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

and in my view I call this,  with a helper to render the pagination in a sexy twitter bootsrap style:

```
<%= will_paginate @collection, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I handled this in my routes file by doing something like so:

```
  resources :links
    get "(?page=:page)#show-links" => "links#index", :as => :links
```

BOOYA!